# Set application default payment service

Tags: android, nfc, hce, android-tap-and-pay

Let's think about a case where user has installed multiple applications capable of NFC HCE payments. Those application services are visible under settings NFC Tap and Pay.

How to programmatically change your application to be the default payment service if it's not?

`CardEmulation` seems only to have API to query if service for category is default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main idea behind having that UI is that **the user** can decide on which payment app should be the default app. Consequently, there is *no* way to *programmatically* set your app to be the default.

However, you can request the user to set your app as default app for the payment category (see [`ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(CardEmulation.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_SERVICE_COMPONENT,
                new ComponentName(this, my.package.MyPaymentService.class));
intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_CATEGORY, CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can we set the translations of locales because currently it shows only default text