# How to detect the default payment method type of a tap and pay wallet app in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, hce

X wallet app that supports only HCE (Host Card Based Emulation) is installed on an Android device that supports both HCE and SE(Secure Element) payment methods. The default 'tap and pay ' app is the X wallet app but the default selected payment method registered to it is SE.

[image]

How can I detect the default payment method? So that I could warn the user to change the payment method type to HCE for the X wallet.

Comment: There is no public api for this on Android yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the Android system that you want your app to manage the tap&pay, and it will display a Dialog with the name of the app the actually manages the payment along with the name your app.

This is explained in the answer to the question:
[Set application default payment service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164233/set-application-default-payment-service)

The code you can find there is the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(CardEmulation.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_SERVICE_COMPONENT,
            new ComponentName(this, my.package.MyPaymentService.class));
intent.putExtra(CardEmulation.EXTRA_CATEGORY, CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT);

startActivity(intent);
```

where "my.package.MyPaymentService" is the service in your app that manage the payment.

Comment: I think you can detect if _your app_ is the default, but you cannot figure out what app _is_ the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private boolean isGoogleWalletDefaultPaymentMethod(){
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
CardEmulation cardEmulation = CardEmulation.getInstance(manager.getDefaultAdapter());
if (cardEmulation.getDescriptionForPreferredPaymentService().equals("Google Pay"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```